write pdf in a range in python
How do i increase this code list to work on a wider range
it's working fine for 200 files
File "F:\New folder\Tarek\New folder\Merger2.py", line 14, in merge_pdf
matching_draft = [f for f in second_list if key in f][0]
IndexError: list index out of range 

The Code
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger #pip install PyPDF2


def merge_pdf(first_folder , second_folder ,output_folder):
        # if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
              #  os.mkdir(output_folder)

        first_folder = [f for f in os.listdir(first_folder) if f.endswith('.pdf')]
        second_folder = [f for f in os.listdir(second_folder) if f.endswith('.pdf')]

        for pdf in first_folder :
                key = pdf.split('.')[0]
                print(key)
                matching_draft = [f for f in second_folder if key in f][0]
                merger = PdfMerger()
                merger.append(f"{first_folder}/{pdf}")
                merger.append(f"{second_folder}/{matching_draft}")
                merger.write(f"{output_folder}/merged_file.pdf")
                #merger.write(f'{output_Folder}/{matching_draft}') 
                #print (f'Merged {len(first_folder)} PDFS to {output_folder}')

merge_pdf('first_folder','second_folder','output_folder')


Getting the out put with the same original file name

After the list comprehension (line 14), the code try to acess an index that not exists if the list is empty.
Try checking the length of matching_draft or implementing a try/except:
matching_draft = [f for f in second_folder if key in f]
try:
    matching_draft = matching_draft[0]
except IndexError:
    # empty list

